# GKE node with DiskPressure: true is not replaced although --auto-repair is set

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using GKE and one of nodes runs out of disk space constantly.

[image]

Is there any way to configure GKE so that it will automatically replace those nodes?

Comment: as mitigation plan you can add a new node into the cluster, which should give the cluster a bit more room to schedule the pods needed for the jobs. You can [resize a cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/resizing-a-cluster) to increase or decrease the number of nodes in a cluster

Comment: By auto-healing you mean auto-repair[1] ? Auto-repair will replace the node only if the node run out of disk for an extended period of time (30 mins).

One other thing to check is images size, if your container images are too big(multiple GB's  they could cause disk pressure). 


[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair

Comment: @boredabdel yes auto-repair

Comment: Can you ssh into the node that has disk pressure and run df -h to check disk utilization and df -i to check inode availability and share the results here

Answer (score 0):

Some of these [metrics](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/review-disk-metrics) may give you some insights.